# Find the nearest index j such that A[ j ] > A[ i ]

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The question is pretty straight forward:

Given an array A of numbers, for every index i, find the nearest index j such that A[j] > A[i]. If none exist, report −1. Output these indices sorted by the corresponding i.

The code I am thinking is below, but is there a faster algorithm to do it?

```
// Calculate element closest to the left
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while (stack.top() < a[i]) {
        stack.pop();
        stack_pos.pop();
    }

    left[i] = stack.top();
    left_pos[i] = stack_pos.top();
    left_pos = stack_pos.top();
    stack.push(a[i]);
    stack_pos.push(i);
}

// Similarly populate right

// Take closest of left and right
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
    closest[i] = closest(left[i], right[i], left_post[i], right_pos[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should show your code and ask questions about problems you've encountered while developing it. As it is, it looks like you want someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: what is your problem with it? show us the code pls

Answer (score 0):

Scan the array and for all the non-peak elements, find the neighbour that is larger than them.

For all the peak elements, push them in another array along with their original index values. Repeat the above procedure in a similar manner (but taking into account the neighbours' original indices).

We will have to make at most log(n) iterations because at each stage only the peak elements remain.